# Durandal - dispose of viewmodel after completion of registration process

Tags: mvvm, durandal, hottowel

Just wondering if anyone knows a good/simple approach using Durandal to disposing of or re-initializing a viewmodel once it becomes invalid?

I have a registration form that I could 're-initialize' manually after a user has completed the form and registered successfully, but I'd prefer to just dispose of it so that Durandal creates a new registraion view/view model when that particular route is accessed again.

Answer (score 0):

If your viewmodel module returns a function rather than an object, it will create a new one each time rather than reusing the 'singleton' object. See the **Module Values** section of [Creating a Module](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module/).

Comment: I don't always want to recreate it - I only want to recreate if the user has completed the registration form.

Answer (score 0):

Updated link for the Durandal Module constructor function information: [Module Values](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module.html)

You can split the difference:

```
var cache;
var ctor = function () {
    if (cache) return cache;
    // init logic
    cache = this;
}
```

Just replace the if(cache) check with whatever "do I need a new thing or not" logic you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using routing, simply redirect the user to an instance-based module (one that returns a constructor function). The user will most likely click or touch a button that signifies that he is done with the registration form.  That would be the redirect action.

If you're using composition, you would still create an instance-based module.  Then, you would use dynamic composition to swap it in once the user signified he was done with the registration form.

*Dynamic composition* is where the view and/or model attributes on a Durandal composition are, themselves, observables, referencing something like the following in the viewModel:

```
this.currentView = ko.observable('');
this.currentModel = ko.observable('');
```

Then, in your HTML:

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="compose: {view: currentView(), model: currentModel())"></div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks "Done", or something to that effect, functions on your viewModel might look something like:

```
ctor.prototype.done = function () {
    this.setCurrentView('viewmodels/registrationForm.html');
    this.setCurrentModel('viewmodels/registrationForm.js');
}

ctor.prototype.setCurrentView = function (view) {
    this.currentView(view);
}

ctor.prototype.setCurrentModel = function (model) {
    this.currentModel(model);
}
```

**Either one of the approaches above will create the registrationForm only when it's needed.**

Answer (score 0):

With Durandal 2.0, you can use the deactivate callback within the composition lifecycle. Here is some documentation http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks